# Where is the archive.key for backports.debian.org?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/how-to-build-pd-extended-on-the-raspberry-pi) in order to install puredata on my Pi. I'm getting the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553
```

When I try `sudo apt-get update` with the repositories in:

1. http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/
2. http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports

So I tried `sudo wget -O - http://backports.org/debian/archive.key | apt-key add -` but there is no server at backports.org. So my question is where is the archive.key for these repositories?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this answer: [No PUbKey Error](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error).

I am not sure but I think you only need the generic debian key here.  I tried it on my system and it added ok.  Let me know if that resolves it for your use.

So, to be clear, and using the OP as source for the key in the following example:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  8B48AD6246925553      
gpg -a --export 8B48AD6246925553 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: This looks like it was a good answer since it was upvoted and accepted.  Can you include the essential parts of the answer from the link here so that link rot can be avoided? I will upvote you when you do.

Comment: In the error message that you get - at the end, you should see a code.  In the OP, "...because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553"
 where "8B48AD6246925553" is the key in question.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the specific soulution based on the key from the OP.  Hope that helps!

Comment: if pgpkeys.mit.edu doesn't work, try with keyserver.ubuntu.com instead

Comment: Also of note, you may get *two* `NO_PUBKEY` errors -- you'll need to repeat this process for each one.

Answer (score 12):

In my case a different key ID was missing when I tried to install backports.
The answer above +1 also worked on my raspberry pi3 with raspbian jessie. I'm writing this just to make a point that you can install missing keys with the same method. Bash terminal message was this:

> Get:4 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main armhf Packages [690 kB]
>   Get:5 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en [488 kB]
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
>   7638D0442B90D010

All I had to do is replace the **key ID** to match the one i was missing, in my case `7638D0442B90D010`

`gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key [Insert here your missing key ID]` 
then
`gpg -a --export [Insert here your missing key ID] | sudo apt-key add -`

Now as usual you can properly fetch your raspbian softwares updates with:
`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: that saved my afternoon :-)

Answer (score 12):

Running the command

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  8B48AD6246925553
```

didn't work for me. gpg baild out with

```
gpgkeys: key 8B48AD6246925553 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I managed to get it to work using

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 8B48AD6246925553
```

After that, `sudo apt-get update` worked fine.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you for updating an old question with a more recent workable answer.

Comment: pgpkeys.mit.edu also didn't work for me, so I tried with keyserver.ubuntu.com and that worked like a charm :) thanks! :)